# How to statically assert a common property of many classes

Tags: c++, boost, static-assert

Let's say I have 3 classes. I expect sizeof() each class to be exactly the same--say 512 bytes.

How can I use something like `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` to apply to all of them such that

1. I only need to use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` in a single place (DRY principle)
2. Evaluated once at compile-time and not run-time

Note: we can use whatever C++ techniques we want (create more class , use inheritance, etc)

My naive solution is presented below:

```
class A { ...stuff }; BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(A) == 512 );
class B { ...stuff }; BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(B) == 512 );
class C { ...stuff }; BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof(C) == 512 );
```

Comment: Why do you need to assert that the sizes will all be 512 (or some other magic number)? I ask because that usually tells you whether you need to repeat yourself and where such a test should go if you don't want to repeat yourself.

For example, if 512 is the size of a cache line, then you need to associate A, B, and C with some concept of "fits a cache line exactly" and express that somewhere.

Comment: The reason is because all of those classes are related, though one commonality is that their sizes are required to be exactly 512 bytes long. So why the different classes? This is because A, B, and C express different types of messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work with gcc 4.0.1 and boost 1.39:

```
template <typename T, size_t S>
struct enforce_size
{
    enforce_size()
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof( T ) == S );
    }
};

class A: enforce_size<A,512> { /* stuff */ };
```

Comment: Nikolai: by doing it that way, for each time class A is instantiated, does it pay for the BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT cost?

Comment: The cost is at compile time for each separate derivation. There is no run-time cost to this (assuming the compiler does empty base optimization.)

Answer (score 1):

As those classes have no relationship, I see now way to do this because you have to be explicit about witch types you want to be checked.

The only DRY way to enforce this is what Nikolai N Festissov proposed. I was writting a similar example with some minor modifications, but the global idea is to make a boost::nocopy - like class that will force the child class to be of a given size.

```
template< typename CheckedType, size_t FixedSize >
class SizeChecked // simple, no inheritance overload
{
public:
    SizeChecked()
    {
        // c++0x or compilers with static_assert() available
        //static_assert( sizeof( CheckedType ) == FixedSize, "Type size check failed!" );
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( sizeof( CheckedType ) == FixedSize );
    }

};

template< typename CheckedType >
class Size512 : public SizeChecked< CheckedType, 512 > // simple, no inheritance overload
{}; 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class A : Size512< A > // automatically check
{
};


class B : Size512< B > // automatically check
{
    std::array< char, 512 > m_array;
};

class C : SizeChecked< C, 1 >
{
    char m_char;
};

class D : SizeChecked< D, 4 >
{
    short m_k;
    char m_u;

};


int wmain()
{
    // need instantiation to be checked !
    //A a; // will trigger the assertion at compile time
    B b; // sizeof(B) == 512 : will be fine
    C c; // sizeof(C) == 1 : will be fine
    //D d; // will fail because sizeof( short ) + sizeof( char ) != 4 !

}
```

Beware : if you loose inheritance you still have to provide an explicit check on the child classes, the check is not inherited!

By the way, a possible way to be more DRY would be to put all your static assertion in only one place.